# I'm having problems getting selected text from a radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list being populated from a dataset. I cannot seem to get the text of a selected radio button. I have tried:

```
string strTime = rblMybuttonList.SelectedValue.ToString();
string strTime = rblmtButtonList.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

When I debug the strings are empty, and passing empty values to my database.

Comment: Can you show how you populate that radiobutton list?

Comment: int nSelecteddestination = ddDestination.SelectedIndex;
            TravelClass.FillData(nSelecteddestination);
            DataSet dsReturn = TravelClass.dsRadio;

            rblDestination.DataSource = dsReturn;
            rblDestination.DataTextField = "DepartureTime";
            rblDestination.DataValueField = "CityID";
            rblDestination.DataBind();
            rblDestination.RepeatColumns = 2;

Comment: Sorry I should have formatted it better...

Comment: Where's that? On page load and "protected" by `Page.IsPostback`?

Comment: I'm actually thinking its the postback causing my variables to go empty...i'm going to try taking out the if(!ispostback) from the page load and put it in the buttonclick method..

Comment: It's correct to have `!IsPostback` on page load method, no need to move it from there. Button click handler is only executed on post back

Comment: Yea, I just noticed switching it around and it made it worse, so I put the if(!ispostback) back in the page load event. But if my button causes the postback then that doesn't make my radiobuttonlist show. So I need to somehow let the radiobuttonlist stay after the posting back of the button..Any suggestions on how I can do that?